# Bootstrap <h> line after do not fit div after rotate

Tags: css, gridview, rotation, size

I'm working on a project based on bootstrap grid. The main page (gallery of projects) is based on thumbnails of pictures with the inscription and line: after or: before. One of the subtitles is inverted by -90 degrees. Unfortunately, the reversal of `<h>` does not make the line: after retains its length and runs out of the `<div>` area, overlaps with another thumbnail.

**effect**

[image: effect]

So I came up with another way. On the server I rotated the image by 90 degrees, making it vertical. Now it's working with the line's longitude and sticking to its side. Unfortunately, after rotation, the image does not scale in `<div>`.

**effect**

[image: effect]

One and the other does not work at all. My concern is how to fix it, it must look like this and be responsive in bootstrap.

**should be**

[image: should be]

Comment: If you need help you'll have to add a [mcve] here, in the question, so we could see the actual markup. You also need to specify in clear what version of Bootstrap you are using. differences between v4 and v3 are considerable.

Comment: I forgot to add: evrything is here: https://codepen.io/kamilsien/pen/MOEQQm  
I use Bootstrap v4.

Comment: I codepen I can add grid.css so I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

If some one will have problem like that, this is solution (not mine, friends, but work :)) :

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

h2 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
}

h2.left:before {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto 0em;
  height: 0;
  margin-right: .3em;
  border-top: solid black 3px;
}

h2.right:after {
  content: '';
  flex: 1;
  margin: auto 0em;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: .3em;
  border-top: solid black 3px;
}

.edgetop {
  margin-bottom: -.3rem;
}

.edgetopmore {
  margin-bottom: -.3rem;
  z-index: 2;
}

.edgebottom {
  margin-top: -.3rem;
}

.rotation-link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.text-wrap {
  width: 1.4rem;
  align-self: stretch;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.text-wrap h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.text-wrap h2::after {
  width: 9999px;
}

.img-wrap {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.img-wrap img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<a href="index.html" class="rotation-link">
 <div class="text-wrap">
   <h2 class="right edgetop zodiac">header</h2>
 </div>
<div class="img-wrap">
  <img src="https://sl.d.umn.edu/och/PhotoGallery/no-image-available.jpg" alt="Image" />
</div>
</a>
</div>
```